# ClassifierFunction output dependent on current $ContextPath

Tags: machine-learning, contexts

I'm trying to use `Classify` to predict heads in a Mathematica expression from the heads of its arguments, which may be functions whose heads are not on the current `$ContextPath`. With the default method `"LogisticRegression"`, the behavior is as expected-- output does not depend on `$ContextPath`.

```
a = Test`testA;
b = Test`testB;

clf = Classify[{{a}->1, {b}->2}];

clf[{a}, "Probabilities"]
Block[{$ContextPath = {"Test`"}}, clf[{a}, "Probabilities"]]
clf[{"foo"}, "Probabilities"]

(*
<|1 -> 0.999679, 2 -> 0.000321061|>
<|1 -> 0.999679, 2 -> 0.000321061|>
<|1 -> 0.999997, 2 -> 3.21752*10^-6|>
*)
```

However, when I set `"Method" -> "Markov"`, the symbol is treated as equivalent to an unknown symbol when its context is on `ContextPath`.

```
clf2 = Classify[{{a}->1, {b}->2}, "Method" -> "Markov"];

clf2[{a}, "Probabilities"]
Block[{$ContextPath = {"Test`"}}, clf2[{a}, "Probabilities"]]
clf2[{"foo"}, "Probabilities"]

(*
<|1 -> 0.916597, 2 -> 0.0834028|>
<|1 -> 0.5, 2 -> 0.5|>
<|1 -> 0.5, 2 -> 0.5|>
*)
```

Since `SequencePredict` always uses `Method -> Markov`, it always has the second behavior. This seems to be an issue, since `$ContextPath` changes when loading packages.

- Is this a bug? (I have already contacted Wolfram Research.)
- What's the root cause? `Hash` doesn't depend on `$ContextPath`, and overloading `ToString` has no effect.
- Is there an elegant workaround other than hashing the input manually (which doesn't work well for `SequencePredict`)? Enclosing every use of the `ClassifierFunction` in `` Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`"}},...] `` doesn't work.